# Handling Push notification

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I am working with push notification, when the application is opened/or in backgroung process then it is no problem for me to receive the push notification, the problem occurs when i quit my application, it is not calling my delegate. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When an app is launched from a push notification, the code path is a little different. Instead of getting the `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` message, your app delegate gets some extra information passed into its `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. You can get the notification dictionary out of the options one and hand it off to your regular push-notification handler, like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    NSDictionary *pushDict = [options objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if(pushDict)
    {
        [self application:app didReceiveRemoteNotification:pushDict];
    }

    // etc.
}
```